# Make fails to export the 'SHELL' variable

Tags: makefile

Make fails to export the 'SHELL' variable.

The [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html#Choosing-the-Shell) reads:

> Furthermore, when you do set 'SHELL' in your makefile that value is
>   *not* exported in the environment to recipe lines that 'make' invokes.
>   Instead, the value inherited from the user's environment, if any, is
>   exported.  You can override this behavior by explicitly exporting
>   'SHELL' (*note Communicating Variables to a Sub-'make':
>   Variables/Recursion.), forcing it to be passed in the environment to
>   recipe lines.

And further [elsewhere](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html#Variables_002fRecursion), we have:

> The value of the 'make' variable 'SHELL' is not exported.  Instead,
>   the value of the 'SHELL' variable from the invoking environment is
>   passed to the sub-'make'.  You can force 'make' to export its value for
>   'SHELL' by using the 'export' directive, described below.

```
ifeq "$(MAKELEVEL)" "0"

export SHELL

all:
    @$(MAKE)

else

all:
    @-foo;

endif


.PHONY: all
```

running as:

```
$ make SHELL=bash -e
```

We get:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname'
/bin/sh: 1: foo: not found
makefile:13: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: [all] Error 127 (ignored)
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname'
```

If you take a close look at the 2nd line above, you'll see that the **default** (`/bin/sh`) shell executed the commands.

Now, that's despite of an explicit `export` on the SHELL variable, as advised by the docs, cited above. Why?

Make version is the latest!

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of odd.  The problem is you're using `-e` (allow environment variables to override make variables).  If you don't use that flag, then it works as expected.

When you do specify `-e`, then the sub-make does get the exported value of `SHELL`, and it does pass that value to its commands, but it uses `/bin/sh` itself to run commands.

Consider this makefile:

```
ifeq "$(MAKELEVEL)" "0"

export SHELL

all: ; @env | grep ^SHELL; $(MAKE)

else

$(info submake SHELL = $(SHELL))
all: ; @-env | grep ^SHELL; foo

endif

.PHONY: all
```

Now if we run without `-e` we get what we expect:

```
$ make SHELL=bash
SHELL=bash
submake SHELL = bash
SHELL=bash
bash: foo: command not found
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: [all] Error 127 (ignored)
```

But if we run with `-e`, then all is the same relative to exported `SHELL` values but the sub-make uses `/bin/sh` to run recipes:

```
$ make -e SHELL=bash
SHELL=bash
submake SHELL = /bin/sh
SHELL=bash
/bin/sh: foo: command not found
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: [all] Error 127 (ignored)
```

I'm not really sure why the `-e` has this effect; I'd need to look at the code.